# Python list won't reset after going through this

Tags: python, random

I am running an empty list through the following function, the list being `gp`. The idea was to append a letter to the end of the list, then reset it once it reached a length of 9. However, it just stops appending new letters once `gp` reaches 9 characters.

`def upd(gp):
    gp.append(random.choice(string.letters))
    if len(gp) > 9:
        gp = []`

Comment: @mhawke has the answer - I'll just point out that this is a common newbie error in languages that have implicit reference semantics (variables and parameters act as references to the real object rather than the value of that object, but with implicit dereferencing for most operations other than assigning from another implicit reference to an object, which copies the reference not the object). There's advantages of course - references are quick and cheap to pass around, implicit references reduce clutter etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `gp = []` does not mutate list `gp`, it simply rebinds the *local* variable `gp` to be an empty list. The external list (that was passed to the function in `gp`) is not affected by this rebinding.

What you need to do is to explicitly remove the items from the list. You can remove all items in one go like this:

```
def upd(gp):
    gp.append(random.choice(string.letters))
    if len(gp) > 9:
        gp[:] = []
```

Now this will mutate the list `gp` in place, effectively removing all its items. There are other ways to do it, e.g. `del gp[:]` will also work, and `gp.clear()` in Python 3 (thanks @PeterDeGlopper).